# Redux dispatch won't change my initialState

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux

Seems like dispatch is not working as it is supposed to be.

Here is my code.

Wrapper.js

```
...
const Wrapper = ({ action, variable }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    action();
  }, []);

  return(
    <Text>{variable.toString()}</Text>
  );
};
...
```

Actions.js

```
export const action = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({
    type: MY_TYPE,
    payload: true,
  });
};
```

Reducer.js

```
...
const initialState = {
  variable: false,
};

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch(actions.types) {
    case MY_TYPE:
      return {
        ...state,
        variable: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
...
```

When i do `console.warn('test')` inside my action function, i get the yellow message "test" so i assume that everything is fine with my code. But given the code above, in my `<Text>` i always get `false`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have typo in your reducer. There is `actions.types`.
Should be `action.type`.

Also, I see you use function instead of object for an action. Make sure you have redux-thunk middleware applied and there is no problem with your connect hoc in `Wrapper.js`

Comment: Yes in my original code i have ``` action.type ``` so this is just a typo. There is no problem at all.. All my other action functions are working great.

Comment: oh.. i had a typo in my code aswell.. i had ``` action.types ``` instead of ``` action.type ```.. God such a fool mistake